# HTTP inputstream class (C++)

Tags: c++, http, inputstream

I'm currently working on a project that does a lot of HTTP requests for data that it needs. It works by writing all the data into a buffer, then returning that buffer to the caller. It seems that waiting for the entire file to download data that can essentially streamed is a bad idea.

Question 1: Is there already a library / public code that can make HTTP and Authenticated HTTP requests that works as a stream?

Question 2: If there is no such library, why not? Is there a reason such a thing was never needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of an existing library, but it shouldn't be too hard to wrap [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (or [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630(VS.85).aspx), if that's your cup of tea) with [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be too hard to get [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) to do this, but as far as I know, it doesn't have HTTP protocol built-in (and I can't think of a library that does, or why not), so you'd have to write header/body parsing (could be tedious and error-prone).

Some googling came up with some attempts at this, [like so](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/cpp/BoostAsioProxy.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are many C libraries that handle http requests, and the reason they're in C rather than C++ is simply because C++ can *easily* use the C libraries, but the converse isn't quite true.

Therefore, a C library is useful in both worlds...

[libwww](http://www.w3.org/Library/) is the W3C library for http functions.

[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) also has a library with a C++ [wrapper](http://rrette.com/curlpp.html) project too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/urdl/